# Adding php function in html class

Tags: php, html

I am performing some server side validations and I want to style the rows depending on the PHP variable. For example, if PHP variable is 2 the row should be styled to **green** else **red**.

I was thinking to add a php function in the html but it doesn't work. What is the best practice to accomplish that?

```
<tr class="<?php add_red();?>">
 <td>
  <input class="w3-radio" name="reflexive" type="radio" id="reflexiveYES" value="yes">
 </td>
</tr>

function add_red(){
    //inside validation.php
    if($a == 2){
        return "w3-green"; //class for changing the background
    }
    return "w3-red";
}
```

Comment: You're returning a value but you're not echoing it

Comment: Don't need a function for this - assuming `w3-green` and `w3-red` are CSS classes... `<input class="w3-radio <?= $a == 2 ? "w3-green" : "w3-red"; ?>" name="reflexive" type="radio" id="reflexiveYES" value="yes" />`

Comment: But what if she has 20000 rows and decides to change it? Function is pretty useful here.

Comment: @MichałSkrzypek - if there are 20000 rows and they're not being generated dynamically in a `foreach()` loop there's probably a bigger problem overall ;)

Comment: Problem is that the validation.php file is a different file than the index.php (which the html is located)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a function to do this, try this:

```
<tr class="<?php echo ($a == 2) ? 'w3-green' : 'w3-red'; ?>">
 <td>
  <input class="w3-radio" name="reflexive" type="radio" id="reflexiveYES" value="yes">
 </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: the variable $a is in a different file.

Comment: @Eternal: ok, how about your function?

Comment: @Eternal: you can add that variable into global array!

Answer (score 2):

Your function returns a value you specified, but you need a command to actually print it:

```
<tr class="<?php echo add_red();?>">
 <td><input class="w3-radio" name="reflexive" type="radio" id="reflexiveYES" value="yes">
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hey, I answered that earlier 

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to output the value. Just put `echo` before `add_red` call

Answer (score 0):

First of all pass a parameter in your function.
The function structure should like the following:

```
function add_red( $a ){
    //inside validation.php
    if($a == 2){
        echo"w3-green"; //class for making the background red
    } else {
        echo"w3-reed"
    }
}
```

Then call the function in html

```
<tr class = "<?php add_red(2); ?>">
    <td>
        <input class="w3-radio" name="reflexive" type="radio" id="reflexiveYES" value="yes">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I wouldn't print right in the function. who knows where else you gonna run it. And it's not testable.

Comment: If you wouldn't print right the function then use the following. This is tested
function add_red( $a ){
    //inside validation.php
    if($a == 2){
        return "w3-green"; //class for making the background red
    } else {
        return "w3-reed";
    }
}

Comment: Okey, could you please show me the unit test example for this function?

Comment: Yeah that's better :)

Comment: Nope, it is not the variable the problem. I use a standard return into the function without a variable but it still doesn't work. Only if I use the code in the same file it works. It doesn't recognize that the function exists in that file

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to print that value, something like this:

```
<tr class="<?php echo add_red();?>">
    <td>
        <input class="w3-radio" name="reflexive" type="radio" id="reflexiveYES" value="yes">
    </td>
</tr>

<?php
function add_red(){
    //inside validation.php
    if($a == 2){
    return "w3-green"; //class for chaning the background
    } else {
    return "w3-red";
    }
}
?>
```

Ensure that you define `$a` inside your function or you'll get an error

Comment: what if the variable is in a different file ?

Comment: You'll need to include that file with `require`, or `include`